# Rigify error "NoneType" "Bones" when trying to Generate Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, error, rigify

I am trying to rig a character using Rigify but I run into this error when I hit "generate rig".

The error says "Generation has thrown an exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bones'.

I have modified the rig in edit mode, however I have done so before with rigify and never ran into this problem.

[image]

Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dG_hfjoPC-0QzFdUP0qCrWlxB2T1Le3F/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your file 1.5GB :) I'll take a look but you could delete the character and upload it again. We only need the meta rig to check the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for one reason or another the "Rig Type" is missing from your spine. Sometimes that happens due to a bug in Blender itself.

The fix is easy. In your **MetaRig** select the bone I have highlighted in the image. Make sure you're in **Pose Mode**! Go to Bone tab and under Rigify Type choose *spines.basic_spine*
Make sure your generated rig is visible and press Generate Rig. That should fix the non type error.

[image]

If you're interested, the error itself comes from the head/neck, because it has the "connect chain" option ON. This requires it to be snapped to another chain of bones. But since the Rig Type was missing, Rigify just ignores the Spine bone chain. And that produces the error.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! this has been bothering me for DAYS!

Comment: Nice, glad it was resolved!